# Updating a gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm using the twitter gem and it has a mistake in one the methods -- Twitter requires authentication and this method was set for fals for authentication. It seems someone fixed it with this commit ver recently:

https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/commit/4483ad062c5dd65b4adb13fb8da5efdaf550f35a#

But, when I use the method -- I still get an error:

```
Twitter::Unauthorized: GET https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweets/{id}.json: 401: Could not authenticate you.
```

I tried updating the gem.

```
gem update twitter
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
```

I tried also, updating the bundle, but no luck. So, I'm not sure how to get the new code into my bundle so it uses the method with authentication?

Comment: that commit changes nothing, it seems only the comment is modified

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commit you are linking to seems to be a documentation change only so getting it wouldn't probably help much. If you want to link to the latest git version of a gem you can put something like this in your gemfile:

```
gem "twitter", :git => "git://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter.git"
```

If you want to change a piece of the code just fork the repo on twitter and link to your own instead locally or on github.

**Update**: nowadays it is also possible to have a `github` reference in the gemfile:

```
gem "twitter", :github => "jnunemaker/twitter"
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. Not sure why they'd change just the documentation and not the method itself.

Answer (score 2):

As Pablo Fernandez noted, the commit you linked changed nothing, just a comment. Also, just because there's a commit, it does not mean that there's a new gem version released. You can try to switch your dependency on the Gemfile to the "live" version, though:

```
gem "twitter", :git => "git://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter.git"
```

Comment: I tried that and go all kinds of errors when trying to run IRB or the server. Not sure what broke exactly, something with one of the dependencies.

Comment: solved that problem. Looks like faraday and omniauth (which I'm also using) didn't play nice together. Updating omniauth fixed it.

Comment: @Final if that's it then accept any answer so this question can be properly resolved